# Using operators from different namespaces in std::find

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I have the following code that is automatically generated:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace foo{  
    struct S{};
    namespace inner{
        bool operator==(const S&,const S&){return true;}
    }
}

namespace bar{
    void func();
}
```

I now want to search a container for a `S` object using STL's `find` algorithm:

```
void bar::func(){
    std::vector<foo::S> v;
    foo::S s;
    std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),s);
}
```

However I get this error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17:
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'foo::S' and 'const foo::S')

  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

Even after adding `using foo::inner::operator==;` I get the same error:

```
void bar::func(){
    using foo::inner::operator==;
    std::vector<foo::S> v;
    foo::S s;
    std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),s);
}
```

However, when I do this it works:

```
void bar::func(){
    std::vector<foo::S> v;
    foo::S s;
    std::find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[s](foo::S e){
        using foo::inner::operator==;
        return s==e;
    });
}
```

My two questions are:

- Why is the first example giving an error? (after adding the `using` )
- How can it be fixed? (without changing the generated code)

Edit:

Thanks to Max's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55517500/8900666) I found a way to fix this issue (a bit ugly but works):

```
// Generated code
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace foo{  
    struct S{};
    namespace inner{
        bool operator==(const S&,const S&){return true;}
    }
}
namespace bar{
    void func();
} 

// My code
namespace foo{
    using inner::operator==;
}

void bar::func(){
    std::vector<foo::S> v;
    foo::S s;
    std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),s);
}
```

Comment: @LeonardoFaria Exactly *where* do you add the `using` statement?

Comment: I'll add a snippet with the `using` for better understanding

Comment: @LeonardoFaria - Thank you!

Comment: added the snippet (it's the 2nd to last)

Comment: The first case doesn't work because of ADL - the compiler looks in namespace `foo` not `foo::inner` for the `operator==`.   Add a `using inner::operator==` in namespace `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL).

Somewhere within the `std::find` template, there is a `if (*it == value)`, where `value` and `it` are dependent types. This means that the compiler will wait until the template is instantiated to look for the correct `operator==` to use.

But the places it looks for an `operator==` are more or less limited to (without going too deep into the details of unqualified name lookup):

- All enclosing namespaces - but search here stops on finding *any* `operator==`. (Not relevant for you, but can trip up people that just add operators for e.g. `std` objects into the global namespace, such as "supporting" `operator+` for `std::vector`).
- ADL is performed - the namespaces of the objects (where `*it` and `*value` are from)  are searched for matching `operator==`.

But the `operator==` that you want to use cannot be found that way - it is in a different (deeper) namespace. This is basically a fault in the generated code - **operators should always reside in the same namespace as the one that the objects they operate on are defined in.**

So the answers are:

1. Your `operator==` isn't found because it's in the wrong namespace.
2. There is no issue here because within the lambda the correct operator is found, and `std::find_if` just uses the lambda directly (no lookup at all).

Comment: But surely adding the `using` statement will add `inner::operater==` to the global namespace.

Comment: @MartinBonner In the scope of wherever you put that `using`. That's exactly why the second case works. But it's not going to magically make it in-scope for the entrails of `std::find`.